# Problems with laravel forms

Tags: php, forms, laravel

My Form:

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => array('UserMessageController@store', Route::input('user')), 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true]) }}
  <textarea name="text"></textarea><br>
  <input type="file" name="attachment" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><br>
  <input type="submit">
{{ Form::close() }}
```

This function can't transmit argument `Route::input('user')` in the `store` method:

```
public function store($userId)
{
    $message = new Message;

    $message->text = Input::get('text');
    $message->user_id_from = Auth::id();
    $message->user_id_to = $userId;
    $message->save();

    require('MessageAttachmentController.php');
    MessageAttachmentController::store($message->id);

    return Redirect::to("contact/$userId/message/create");
}
```

maybe problem is in routes.php?

```
  Route::resource('contact', 'UserMessageController');
  Route::get('contact/{user}/message/create', 'UserMessageController@create');
  Route::post('contact/{user}/message/create', 'UserMessageController@store');
```

debug window:
[image]

Comment: use that:
`{{Form::open(array('url'=>'contact/'.$user.'/message/create','method=>'post'))}}`

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'post' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'contact/'. Route::input('user') .'/message/create', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true]) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Form part

{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'contact/store/'.$userId,'method' => 'post','files' => 'true')) !!}

// Route part

Route::post('contact/store/{id}', 'UserMessageController@store');